# show content items based on user date params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have a website with holiday rentals/activities/events in Umbria/Marche(Italy). We have nice content of the area, such as events (model), activities(model) etc. Each model has the attributes start_date and end_date.

I want to make a form with date-fields and ask the visitor what the period is that they want to come to umbria/marche. When the visitor submits the data I want the entries of events and activities that are showed of the 'user' period. I can make the form/calendar. But how can I show the correct 'user input based' content in the entire website. Must this be session based?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a session you could also overwrite the url_for helper. You would then add the user's data directly to the url and read it on any subsequent request.

Check this documentation and especially the code at the end of the page: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

I would put that new url_for function in your ApplicationHelper.